# Parse plaintext API response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, api, request

Im getting plaintext responses from an API like these:

[image]

So i would like to parse or pass those values to variables.

Example:

If the response is:

```
TD_OK
3213513
```

I would like to convert this to:

```
TD_Result = TD_OK
TD_Number = 3213513
```

I tried something like this, but did not work:

```
result = """
TD_EXISTS
23433395"""

result2 = []

for r in result:
   result2.append(r)


TD_Result = result2[1]
TD_Number = result2[2]

print (TD_Result)
print (TD_Number)
```

**Any idea about how to do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for r in result:` -> `for r in result.splitlines():`

or

as @Matmarbon said, below will be better

```py
result = """
TD_EXISTS
23433395
"""

td_result, td_number = result.split()
print(td_result)
print(td_number)
```

1. get rid of unnecessary dict
2. use Extended Iterable Unpacking
3. use snake_case to comply with its naming convention

Comment: While this will work, OP clearly has a more fundamental problem that you are not addressing at all. If you insert this into the original code, it will only be part of the nonsensical creation of the duplicate of a list. Generally it is better to write answers that help OP with understanding the problem rather than fixing the specific issue.

Comment: It works! thank you and @Matmarbon for the response and advice! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `split` method as follows.

Also note that list indexes in Python start at zero instead of one.

```
result = """
TD_EXISTS
23433395"""

result2 = result.split()

TD_Result = result2[0]
TD_Number = result2[1]

print (TD_Result)
print (TD_Number)
```